# Converting string to int - datareader

Tags: c#, ado.net

trying to figure out how to conver this zip string to an int.  I get a cast exception:

```
member.Zip = reader.GetInt16(ordinals[(int)Enums.MemberColumn.Zip]);
```

UPDATE:

thanks all.  Here's what I came up with that works for me good enough:

```
Int32.TryParse(reader.GetString(ordinals[(int)Enums.MemberColumn.Zip]), out number) ? number : 0;
```

Comment: what kind of object is reader (datareader?)? Int.Parse? Explicit cast (int) (on the reader object ofc)?

Comment: How about just reader.GetString and int.Parse? Although if the db says it is a string, I'd be tempted to leave it as a string throughout

Comment: Have you tried debugging? What sort of values does your ordinals array hold? What's the value at the index of the value of `Enums.MemberColumn.Zip`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get it as a string and then parse that string:

```
string zipString = reader.GetString(ordinals[(int)Enums.MemberColumn.Zip]);
member.Zip = Int16.Parse(zipString);
```

DataReaders expect the underlying type of the field to be the same as the specific method you're calling. So GetInt16 requires an underlying 16 bit integer, GetBoolean requires an underlying bit, and GetString requires an underlying string. It won't do any conversion for you.

Comment: Yes, you might. Depends on whether you want the program to throw an exception if invalid data is found in the reader.

Answer (score 0):

```
member.Zip = Convert.ToInt16(reader.GetString(ordinals[(int)Enums.MemberColumn.Zip]));
```